# Crabbies ginger beer clone recipe

Tags: ginger-beer, beginner

A few years back I tried brewing my first Ginger beer hoping to get a result that would come close to the one that Crabbies makes (which I love). The result ended up very bitter and it just wasn't a nice drink. That kinda ruined the hobby for me and I gave it up after my first try, but recently I have been thinking about giving it another try. I have tried googling the recipe I used a few years ago, but I did not regcognize it.
So my question is: is there a recipe around that comes close to Crabbies ginger beer? And does anyone have experience in brewing Crabbies clone or similar brews?

Comment: GB means ginger beer? Why don't you use full name for it? Would be a bit easier to read.

Comment: Crabbies Ginger beer is not a real ginger beer. It is an alco-pop, aka, a flavoured soda with added alcohol. Just want to let you know.

Comment: That's interesting. That makes it quite hard to make an accurate clone, since distilling alchohol is not allowed.

Comment: Alcohol isn't produced by distillation. It's produced by fermentation, which is yeast eating sugars, producing alcohol and CO2.

Answer (score 1):

could be a contaminated batch that might be the bitterness.. im terrible at brewing beer only this batch out of six has been any good.. flat and clear or fizzy and cloudy... 
iv had the problem of bitterness in the beer when i was not willing to drink it. only had 3-4L then didn`t like it so left it to  go bad.  timing seems to be the key, also heating pad or belt.. proper cleaning of equipment and bottles

heating pad while fermenting for 5days cool for 2days bottle and prime and back on the heating pad for 5-10 day then store in cold dark place like the fridge   remember 18c is perfect for germs to multiple so keep it clean.. anything in with the beer will be there for the life of the beer

Comment: What is the point of the heating pad? Too much heat, and you're going to either stress the yeast or kill it.

Answer (score 1):

It is bitter due to the ginger and the yeast eating all the sugar. You really should backsweeten. Here is a really good article explaining all the different parts of this.

https://homebrewsupply.com/learn/make-alcoholic-ginger-ale.html

good luck